# PaperJS Rotate function displaying item two times

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, paperjs

when i am trying to rotate the path it is displaying same item two times. can some one help me to prevent the item to display twice.

```
var center1 = ball1.position;
var center2 = ball2.position;

// Create a triangle shaped path 
var triangle = new Path.RegularPolygon(new Point(80, 70), 3, 12);
triangle.id = Math.random();
triangle.fillColor = '#fff';
//triangle.selected = true;
triangle.strokeColor = '#00304A';
triangle.strokeWidth = 2;
triangle.position = path.position; **
var arrowAngle = 90 + ((center2.subtract(center1)).angle); ** triangle.rotation = arrowAngle;
```

Comment: I'm confused why this is tagged both paperjs and fabricjs?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're getting two triangles (there isn't enough code for me to see what the reason for that is) but the main problem is that `rotation` is a read-only property - you cannot set it. Try using `rotate()`.

http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#rotate-angle